# How to use PlantUML Server with Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

[plantuml-mode](https://github.com/skuro/plantuml-mode) supports execution using a PlantUML server, with `(setq plantuml-default-exec-mode 'server)`. I can set the server location with `(setq plantuml-server-url "https://myserver.plantuml.com")`.

However, as far as I can tell, I cannot use a remote PlantUML Server for executing Org Babel blocks with PlantUML source? It [seems to require](https://plantuml.com/emacs) a local **.jar** file defined in `org-plantuml-jar-path`. Can I simply pass a remote URL to this variable to get Org Mode to work the same as PlantUML Mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using `plantuml-mode`, but have used plantuml with Org babel blocks. I'm currently using this setup to use the Plantuml server to render images on GitHub. You may be able to modify to work locally, which could be useful now that a recent Org mode supports rendering remote (HTTP) images.

I'm currently generating the PlantUML source with a Python Babel block like this:

```
#+NAME: plantuml
#+BEGIN_SRC python :file plantuml.out :post plantuml_url :results output raw file drawer
print("@startuml")
print("Bob -> Alice : hello")
print("@enduml")
#+END_SRC
```

(I'm actually using `:var foo` to bring in some output from another code block which I then parse with Python to generate a more complicated diagram).

Anyway, the `plantuml_url` block, called via the `:post` header arg is:

```
#+NAME: plantuml_url
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :exports results :results raw drawer
url=$(java -jar ~/local/src/plantuml.jar -encodeurl ~/path/to/plantuml.out)
echo "#+BEGIN_HTML"
echo "<img src=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/${url}>"
echo "#+END_HTML"
#+END_SRC
```

Which takes the valid PlantUML source in a file generated by the first (Python) block (see `:file`), uses `plantuml` to get the encoded URL, and then spits out some wrapper `#+BEGIN_HTML` and `#+END_HTML` so that GitHub will properly display the HTML `img`.

I don't run this `plantuml_url` bash block - I run the Python `plantuml` block, and it calls `plantuml_url` (via `:post`). The Python block results look like this:

```
#+RESULTS: plantuml
:results:
#+BEGIN_HTML
<img src=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SoWkIImgAStDuNBAJrBGjLDmpCbCJbMmKiX8pSd9vt98pKi1IW80>
#+END_HTML
:end:
```

If you drop the code immediately above into GitHub README.org you won't see anything because it's a `RESULTS` block, and you need a code block above it with `:exports both` or `:exports results` to override the default which is `:exports code`. Or remove the `#+RESULTS:` line.